# How to check if the data I entered does not exist in the column of a jTable?

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

So I am creating a program that will search through the first column of a jtable and find if the value is there then if it is there, it will output in the jTextFields below. I got them right but I don't know how to check if the entered data on the search textfield does not exist on the jtable. I want to output a joptionpane if the data does not exist on that column of jtable.

This is my code.

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String value = jTextField1.getText();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

    for (int r = 0; r <= jTable1.getRowCount() - 1; r++){
        if (value.equals(jTable1.getValueAt(r, 0))) {
            jTable1.setRowSelectionInterval(r, r);
        } 
    }

    String ID = model.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
    String Name = model.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString();

    jTextField2.setText(ID);
    jTextField3.setText(Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...since your search criteria appears to be based from the ID, if ID equals nothing then inform User that nothing was found.

```
String value = jTextField1.getText(); // Search Criteria.
if (value.isEmpty()) {
    return;  // Search criteria is empty. Get outta here.
}

DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

String id = ""
String name = ""
int r; 
for (r = 0; r < model.getRowCount(); r++){
    // Does the current column cell match the search criteria?
    if (value.equals(model.getValueAt(r, 0))) {
        // Yes it does...
        id = model.getValueAt(r, 0).toString();    // Fill id variable
        name = model.getValueAt(r, 1).toString();  // Fill name variable
        jTable1.setRowSelectionInterval(r, r);     // Select JTable Row
        break;  // Break out of loop. Don't need it anymore.
    } 
}

// Search Item Not Found.
if (id.equals("") { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Search Criteria (" + value + 
                                  ") Could No Be Found!", 
                                  "Item Not Found", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    return;  // Get out of method.
}

// Search Item Was Found, Fill JTextFields...
jTextField2.setText(id);
jTextField3.setText(name);
```

And...I'm sure you already know about Java naming conventions. :)